# kdevtmpfsi process is using 100% CPU, restarting on kill

Tags: process, docker, cpu-usage

I have amzon linux instance with docker, rabbitmq and ejabberd installed.

One process is starting and using cpu 100% I'm trying to kill that process but after sometimes it is starting

Top command result

```
22374 root      20   0 2653576   3092   2456 S  99.7  0.0  80:40.24 kdevtmpfsi  


26567 root      20   0  170888   4340   3796 R   0.3  0.1   0:00.02 top

1 root      20   0  117880   6036   3972 S   0.0  0.1   0:22.54 systemd

2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.06 kthreadd

4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H

6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
```

ps -eaf | grep kdevtmpfsi

```
root     22374     1 99 14:25 ?        01:31:02 /tmp/kdevtmpfsi

root     27128 22220  0 15:55 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto kdevtmpfsi
```

Not able to understand What is starting this process??

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like the crypto miner described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59487096/kdevtmpfsi-how-to-find-and-delete-that-miner. Your instance and everything in it is no longer trustworthy and should be destroyed.